# overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded

Tags: sql

Am trying to execute this query but it doesn't like it"it throws the following exception 
"overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded."
Not sure what am missing here

```
    select * from Schedwin.SEVT where 
ltrim(Resid)=345032 and type=5 or (type = 4 and subactid = 4)
or
(TYPE = 0)and (USER2='02-Force OT')
and ltrim(SEVT.t_start) <=  1215208800 
and ltrim(sevt.t_start) <=  1215207800
order by SEVT.TYPE
```

My bad, t_start data type is char so i modified my query like below and it works

```
    select * from Schedwin.SEVT where 
ltrim(Resid)=345032 and type=5 or (type = 4 and subactid = 4)
or
(TYPE = 0)and (USER2='02-Force OT')
and ltrim(SEVT.t_start) <= '1215208800' 
and ltrim(sevt.t_start) <= '1215207800'
order by SEVT.TYPE
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

size of an integer is 4 bytes. You are trying to store more than 4 bytes in a column, overflowing it. Use `bigint` or `nvarchar` as the type for that column. :-) Alter the table.

Answer (score 1):

The highest allowable INT value is 2,147,483,647.
Check your t_start value if it exceeded allowable INT value