# Error Executing Database Query. The conversion of the varchar value '10298866175' overflowed an int column

Tags: sql, sql-server, coldfusion

I'm getting this error:

```
  Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SQLServer JDBC Driver][SQLServer]The conversion of the varchar value '10298866175' overflowed an int column.
```

The FileSize field where the error is occurring is actually an INT field in the SQL Server database.

Unlike a lot of people who posted similar issue, for me this is occurring in an INSERT statement.

```
    INSERT INTO FileTransfer (FileID, Sender, SenderEmail, SenderName, UploadDate, IPAddress, Domain, ClientFileName, ClientFileExt, ContentType, ContentSubType, ServerFile, FileSize, UploadID)

    VALUES (656, 18182, 'joe.blow@mail.mil', 'Jack Martini', CONVERT(DATETIME, '2021-11-06 12:50:13', 102), '126.14.24.43, 172.17', '', 'General', 'zip', 'application', 'octet-stream', '18182_91f1518a-caca-4bbb-91f9-5edcc1526d0c.dat', '10298866175', 366)
```

There is some CFSCRIPT that gets the variables, but this is the actual query pre execution in the Coldfusion code:

```
    <cfquery datasource="#Application.Datasource#" name="AddFile">
    INSERT INTO FileTransfer
    (FileID, Sender, SenderEmail, SenderName, UploadDate, IPAddress, Domain, ClientFileName, ClientFileExt, ContentType, ContentSubType, ServerFile, FileSize, UploadID)
    VALUES (#Variables.FileID#, <cfif IsDefined("Session.UserNUM") and Session.UserNUM gt 0>#Session.UserNUM#<cfelse>NULL</cfif>,
            <cfif Form.SenderEmail is "">NULL<cfelse>'#Form.SenderEmail#'</cfif>,
            <cfif Form.Name is "">NULL<cfelse>'#Form.Name#'</cfif>,
            #UploadDate#,
            '#Trim(Left(session.userIP,20))#',
            '#session.userDomain#',
            <cfif variables.ClientFileName is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.ClientFileName#'</cfif>,
            <cfif variables.ClientFileExt is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.ClientFileExt#'</cfif>,
            <cfif variables.ContentType is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.ContentType#'</cfif>,
            <cfif variables.ContentSubType is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.ContentSubType#'</cfif>,
            <cfif variables.ServerFile is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.ServerFile#'</cfif>,
            <cfif variables.FileSize is "">NULL<cfelse>'#variables.FileSize#'</cfif>,
            #getUploadID.ThisUploadID#);
</cfquery>
```

Changing the data type in the database is not an option. So how would I fix this in Coldfusion or SQL?

Comment: *"Changing the data type in the database is not an option."* Then don't `INSERT` a value that is too large for your column. Those are your 2 options. There is no magic way to make a value large than 2,147,483,647 fit into an `int`; it is stored as a 4 byte signed value. 10,298,866,175 is 5 times too large.

Comment: Then it must be done in Coldfuison. So maybe something like this: <cfif variables.FileSize GT 2147483647>
  <cfset FileSize = 2147483647>
 </cfif> which just sets it to the max value. That would be before done in code before the CFQUERY.

Comment: Also you shouldn't put an `int` in quotes anyway

Comment: @Larnu is right: if you need to store values that large, you'll need to use `bigint` not `int` on the SQL side.

Comment: The best option is to change the data type from `int` to `bigint`.  What is preventing you from doing that?

Comment: At this point you will need to "re-interpret" the size column and store a value in a larger unit of measure. Instead of bytes, you will need to convert the size to kilobytes (or larger) before attempting the INSERT.

Comment: @Smor - Yep, true that's a possible 3rd option. Unfortunately it it will cause a permanent loss of precision since decimals aren't supported for `int` columns. IMO the best option is to modify the column data type to `bigint`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [overflowed an int column. Maximum integer value exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14617775/overflowed-an-int-column-maximum-integer-value-exceeded)

Comment: Thanks for suggestions, but changing the data type isn't an option. I'll write the Coldfusion code to insert like I mentioned in other comment. Also on the screen to the end user, I'll tell them the file size is larger than that value.

Answer (score 1):

It's naturally not possible to store a value greater than the memory it has. `INT` is a 4 byte signed value. If you insist on having an int as datatype you are restricting and applying a constraint for the value to fall in a range from `-2,147,483,647` to `2,147,483,647`

Now to avoid the exception:

1. You can change the type of the field from `int` to `bigint`
2. You can apply validation to pass value that fall in the given range